# Unable to move or rename file via WebDAV

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, webdav, cyberduck

I have a Apache (2.4.7) WebDAV service on port 443 (on Ubuntu). Neither moving nor renaming a file via WebDav is possible. Trying to rename a file in Cyberduck for example, yields a "Bad Gateway" error message. I know that there are issues with the combination of WebDav and SSL. My limited understanding is that Apache basically tries to move the file from a none-secured host to a secured host.

The server setup is rather basic.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...

    Alias /mount /var/www/webdav-folder
    <Location /mount>
            DAV On

            RewriteEngine Off
            ForceType text/plain
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "WebDAV"
            AuthBasicProvider socache dbd

            AuthDBDUserPWQuery [...]

            Require valid-user
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  MultiViews
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I didn't know that, thank you for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by adding

```
RequestHeader edit Destination ^https: http: early
```

to my config file. For an in-depth explanation, see for example here:
http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-03/0549.shtml

The source of this solution is here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html